# Java exception handling Do loop not working?

Tags: java, exception, loops

Here is the code:

```
package classes;
import java.util.*;

public class Introduction {
    Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int classChoose;
    boolean repeat = false;

    public void Introduction() {
        System.out.println("\t===THE QUEST FOR PERSEPOLIS===\tv 1.0\n");
        System.out.println("Please choose a class: ");
        System.out.print("(1)Elite Knight\t");
        System.out.print("(2)Dawnguard\n");
        System.out.print("(3)Archer\t\t\t");
        System.out.print("(4)Barbarian\n");
        System.out.print("(5)Mage\t\t\t");
        System.out.print("(6)Swordsman\n");
        System.out.println("(7)Crossbowman\t");

        do {
            try {
                repeat = false;
                classChoose = Input.nextInt();
                while(classChoose < 1 || classChoose > 7) {
                    repeat = false;
                    System.out.println("Error. Enter a number between 1 and 7(inclusive).");
                    classChoose = Input.nextInt();
                }
            }
            catch(InputMismatchException e) {
                repeat = true;
                System.err.println("Caught: "+e);
                Input.nextLine();
            }
        }while(repeat = true);

        switch(classChoose) {
            case 1: chooseKnight();
                    break;
            case 2: chooseGuard();
                    break;
            case 3: chooseArcher();
                    break;
            case 4: chooseBarbarian();
                    break;
            case 5: chooseMage();
                    break;
            case 6: chooseSwordsman();
                    break;
            case 7: chooseCrossbowman();
                    break;
        }
    }
    public static void chooseKnight() {
        System.out.println("You have chosen the Elite Knight. You will be briefed and then you shall be set "
        +"on your quest!");
    }
    static void chooseGuard() {
        System.out.println("You have chosen the Dawnguard. You will be briefed and then you shall be set "
        +"on your quest!");
    }
    static void chooseArcher() {
        System.out.println("You have chosen the Archer. You will be briefed and then you shall be set "
        +"on your quest!");
    }
    static void chooseBarbarian() {
        System.out.println("You have chosen the Barbarian. You will be briefed and then you shall be set "
        +"on your quest!");
    }
    static void chooseMage() {
        System.out.println("You have chosen the Mage. You will be briefed and then you shall be set "
        +"on your quest!");
    }
    static void chooseSwordsman() {
        System.out.println("You have chosen the Swordsman. You will be briefed and then you shall be set "
        +"on your quest!");  
    }
    static void chooseCrossbowman() {
        System.out.println("You have chosen the Crossbowman. You will be briefed and then you shall be set "
        +"on your quest!");
    }
}
```

Everytime I run it, the program prompts me to choose my class. After I enter my choice, the program does not go on to the switch statement below the do loop. Can someone help me fix this?

-Calvin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an assignment:

```
 while(repeat = true); // Note single '=', not '=='
```

and the result of which will always be `true`, from section [*15.26 Assignment Operators*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26) of the Java Language Specification:

> At run time, the result of the assignment expression is the value of the variable
>   after the assignment has occurred.

Change to:

```
while(repeat);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
while(repeat = true);
```

should be: -

```
while(repeat == true);  // Or better: -  while(repeat);
```

And in your **catch**, change `Input.nextLine()` to `Input.next()` : -

```
catch(InputMismatchException e) {
    repeat = true;
    System.err.println("Caught: "+e);
    Input.nextLine();  // Change to Input.next()
}
```

And your instance variable should begin with a lowercase alphabet or an underscore.. So change `Input` to `input`.